# How do you automatically resize columns in a DataGridView control AND allow the user to resize the columns on that same grid?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am populating a DataGridView control on a Windows Form (C# 2.0 not WPF).

My goal is to display a grid that neatly fills all available width with cells - i.e. no unused (dark grey) areas down the right and sizes each column appropriately according to the data it contains, **but** also allows the user to resize any of the columns to their liking.

I am attempting to achieve this by setting the AutoSizeMode of each column to be **DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells** except for one of the columns which I set to **DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill** in order to ensure the entire area of the grid is neatly filled with data. (I don't mind that when the user attempt to resize this column it springs back to a size that ensures the horizontal space is always used.)

However, as I mentioned, once loaded I would like to allow the user to resize the columns to suit their own requirements - in setting these AutoSizeMode values for each column it appears the user is then unable to then resize those columns.

I've tried not setting the AutoSizeMode of all the columns which does allow resizing BUT doesn't set the initial size according to the data the cells contain. The same result occurs when changing the grid's AutoSizeMode back to "Not Set" after loading the data.

Is there a setting I'm missing here which allows automatic setting of default column widths AND user resizing or is there another technique I must use when populating the DataGridView control?

Comment: dont set it to "Not Set" set it to **"None"**  so resizement **won't revert Back**   -- tested for  c# , .net2.0

Answer (score 168, accepted):

This trick works for me:

```
grd.DataSource = DT;
    
// Set your desired AutoSize Mode:
grd.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
grd.Columns[1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
grd.Columns[2].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
    
// Now that DataGridView has calculated it's Widths; we can now store each column Width values.
for (int i = 0; i <= grd.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
{
    // Store Auto Sized Widths:
    int colw = grd.Columns[i].Width;
    
    // Remove AutoSizing:
    grd.Columns[i].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
    
    // Set Width to calculated AutoSize value:
    grd.Columns[i].Width = colw;
}
```

**In the Code above:**
You set the Columns `AutoSize` Property to whatever `AutoSizeMode` you need.
Then (Column by Column) you store each column Width value (from `AutoSize` value);
Disable the `AutoSize` Property and finally, set the Column Width to the Width value you previously stored.

Comment: I put similar code in a routine named AutoResizeColumnWidthsYetAllowUserResizing. It's called after the grid is populated initially and also after the user edits data (that is, from the grid's CellEndEdit event).

Comment: This is great code. Needs to be put in the 'DataGridView1_DataSourceChanged' event.

Comment: It seems to me that doing `grd.Columns(i).Width = grd.Columns(i).Width`will already do the trick. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32768792/2436175).

Comment: for c# similar but with square brackets  `dataGridView1.Columns[i].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;`

Comment: This might have come very late , but any chance or way, we could resize based on content of a particular row ? Lets say, based on the content of cells in the First Row, irrespective of the width of the cells in other rows?

Comment: @MurtuzaHusain Maybe you could run autosize on a one row temp grid off-camera and transfer those widths to the main grid?

Comment: Following this answer and other suggestions from it I reduced the code to this

    `private void AutoSizeGridColumns(DataGridView grd)
    {
    //set autosize to fill cell contents
    for (int i = 0; i <= grd.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
    {
    grd.Columns[i].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
    grd.Columns[i].Width = grd.Columns[i].Width; //this allows for the width to be user sizable as the AllCells locks it
    }
    }`

Answer (score 53):

Maybe you could call

```
dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill);
```

After setting datasource. It will set the width and allow resize.

More on MSDN [DataGridView.AutoResizeColumns Method (DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158594.aspx).

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer isn't getting more attention.  Much cleaner.  Although if you're looking to match cell content width DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells works a bit better.

Comment: using this solution i'm getting the next error: _"Parameter autoSizeColumnMode is not valid for this operation. It cannot be NotSet, None or Fill but needs to indicate a sizing criteria."_. I ended up using this *dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode  = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;*

Comment: Using DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill doesn't work because it ignores the cell contents when sizing columns.

Comment: I have used this method with `DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells`. In addition, in the Forms Designer, the AutoSizeColumnsMode is set to None. I needed to execute this method call in the DataBindingComplete event handler of the DataGridView, to make sure it always (re)sizes properly.

Comment: One additional note: This will ONLY work after the datagridview has been displayed.  If called during the Form Load event it may not work

Comment: I dont understand all the upvotes... This does not work at all, the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158594.aspx) is clear, doing this leads to an ArgumentException if the autoSizeColumnsMode has the value None or Fill.

Comment: I don't know why but when I was using AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells I was experiencing problems where a combobox column would not expand to fit once I refreshed/reloaded the DGV.  Using this method of AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells); worked great! I no longer am having problems.  I don't know why this works over what I had previously but it does...Thanks! :)

Comment: this may be relevant             `dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;`  and 
            `dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;`

Comment: @Daan you clearly missed a dot (and also, I don't know about the C# convention but perhaps a lowerase d would make clear that it's on the object)?

Comment: I had an exception when using .Fill: "Parameter autoSizeColumnMode is not valid for this operation. It cannot be NotSet, None or Fill but needs to indicate a sizing criteria". Then I change to .AllCells and it worked.

Answer (score 34):

A C# version of  Miroslav Zadravec's code

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count-1; i++)
{
    dataGridView1.Columns[i].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
}
dataGridView1.Columns[dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    int colw = dataGridView1.Columns[i].Width;
    dataGridView1.Columns[i].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
    dataGridView1.Columns[i].Width = colw;
}
```

Posted as Community Wiki so as to not mooch off of the reputation of others

Answer (score 22):

In my application I have set

```
grid.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
grid.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.None;
```

Also, I have set the

```
grid.AllowUserToOrderColumns = true;
grid.AllowUserToResizeColumns = true;
```

Now the column widths can be changed and the columns can be rearranged by the user. That works pretty well for me.

Maybe that will work for you.

Comment: Setting the grid's AutoSizeColumnsMode to "Fill" seems to set all columns to the same widths. Yes the columns are then resizable but the initial widths are all wrong. I may need to set the column widths in code "manually".

Comment: DV- grid.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumn-> **s** <- Mode.Fill;  (you missed the s, it's ColumsMode on the left hand side and the right hand side, so that line of yours doesn't compile)  The code to get datagridview to autosize is very annoying as it is, so at least check your answer first. It's the very first line you wrote and is wrong.

Comment: @barlop thanks for your reply. You have the privileg to edit questions and answers. If you spot a mistake in my code then feel free to edit.

Answer (score 19):

After adding the data to the grid add the following code which will adjust the column according to the length of data in each cell

```
dataGrid1.AutoResizeColumns();            
dataGrid1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
```

Here is the Result

[image]

Comment: Works like charm

Answer (score 11):

Well, I did this like this:

```
dgvReport.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.None;
dgvReport.AutoResizeColumns();
dgvReport.AllowUserToResizeColumns = true;
dgvReport.AllowUserToOrderColumns = true;
```

in that particular order. Columns are resized (extended) AND the user can resize columns afterwards.

Answer (score 11):

A simple two lines of code works for me.

```
dataGridView.DataSource = dataTable;
dataGridView.AutoResizeColumns();
```

Answer (score 6):

If I understood the question correctly there should be an easier way to accomplish what you need. Call 
`dgvSomeDataGrid.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);`

That should do the trick. However, there is one pitfall as you cannot simply call this method directly after populating your DataGridView control. Instead you will have to add an EventHandler for the VisibleChanged event and call the method in there.

Comment: That would resize columns according to content, but would not ensure all available grid space is used. I.e., does not "fill" remaining space if there is any.

Answer (score 5):

Resume of the question:
Have column width adapt to the content (with different method across the column),
but then allow the user to set the column width...

Developing from [Miroslav Zadravec's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1031871/2436175), for me what worked was immediately using the auto computed `column.Width` to set... `column.Width`!

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView.Columns)
{
    if (/*It's not your special column*/)
    {
        column.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
        column.Width = column.Width; //This is important, otherwise the following line will nullify your previous command
        column.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.NotSet;
    }
}

//Now do the same using Fill instead of AllCells for your special column
```

This is tested to work when the `DataGridView` is already created, using a trick like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32750248/2436175).

Comment: I prefer using a foreach as your code does. It makes it more readable when you don't have any math in the top of the loop. I did it that way, and the "column.Width = column.Width;" is interesting.

Answer (score 4):

This autofits all columns according to their content, fills the remaining empty space by stretching a specified column and prevents the 'jumping' behaviour by setting the last column to fill for any future resizing.

```
// autosize all columns according to their content
dgv.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);
// make column 1 (or whatever) fill the empty space
dgv.Columns[1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
// remove column 1 autosizing to prevent 'jumping' behaviour
dgv.Columns[1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
// let the last column fill the empty space when the grid or any column is resized (more natural/expected behaviour) 
dgv.Columns.GetLastColumn(DataGridViewElementStates.None, DataGridViewElementStates.None).AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
```

Comment: I know it's an old answer, but I works nicelly, even when the number of columns is not known in advance.

Answer (score 4):

This did wonders for me:

```
dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);
```

Comment: Simple solution!

Comment: Worked for me only if set to None afterwards, i.e.
`dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);`

            `dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.None;`

Answer (score 2):

Slightly neater C# code from Miroslav Zadravec's code assuming all columns are to be autosized

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgvProblems.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    dgvProblems.Columns[i].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
    int colw = dgvProblems.Columns[i].Width;
    dgvProblems.Columns[i].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
    dgvProblems.Columns[i].Width = colw;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns();

Answer (score 2):

The column widths set to fit its content I have used the bellow statement,
It resolved my issue.

First Step  :

```
RadGridViewName.AutoSize = true;
```

Second Step :

```
// This mode  fit in the header text and column data for all visible rows. 
this.grdSpec.MasterTemplate.BestFitColumns();
```

Third Step  :

```
for (int i = 0; i < grdSpec.Columns.Count; i++) 
{
    // The column width adjusts to fit the contents all cells in the control.
    grdSpec.Columns[i].AutoSizeMode = BestFitColumnMode.AllCells; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another version of Miroslav Zadravec's code, but slightly more automated and universal:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = source;
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1; i++) {
            dataGridView1.Columns[i].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
        }
        dataGridView1.Columns[dataGridView1.Columns.Count].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;

    }

    void Form1Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++ )
        {
            int colw = dataGridView1.Columns[i].Width;
            dataGridView1.Columns[i].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
            dataGridView1.Columns[i].Width = colw;
        }
    }
```

I put second part into separate event, because I fill `datagridvew` in initialization of form and if both parts are there, nothing is changing, because probably autosize calculates widths after `datagridview` is displayed, so the widths are still default in `Form1()` method. After finishing this method, autosize does its trick and immediately after that (when form is shown) we can set the widths by second part of the code (here in `Form1Shown` event). This is working for me like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simplified code for Miroslav Zadravec's answer in c#:

```
CurrentDGV.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader;
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++) dataGridView1.Columns[i].Width = dataGridView1.Columns[i].Width;
CurrentDGV.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.None;
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to set up the `FillWeight` property of your `DataGridViewColumns` object?

For example:

```
this.grid1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
this.grid1.Columns[0].FillWeight = 1.5;
```

I think it should work in your case.

Answer (score 1):

A little improvement from Schnapple's version

```
int nLastColumn = dgv.Columns.Count - 1;
for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    if (nLastColumn == i)
    {
        dgv.Columns[i].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
    }
    else
    {
        dgv.Columns[i].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    int colw = dgv.Columns[i].Width;
    dgv.Columns[i].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
    dgv.Columns[i].Width = colw;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn c in dataGridView.Columns)
    c.Width = c.GetPreferredWidth(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells, true);
```

This should work whether the `dataGridView` has been displayed or not (i.e. even if called from the class constructor).

The same method, but with `DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells`, fails in the above case for the obvious reason - no cell has been displayed yet! For some non-obvious reason, `AutoResizeColumns` also fails in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you bind your datasource to a datatable for example, you need to set the properties after the binding is done:

```
        private void dgv_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
        {
            dgv.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.None;
            dgv.AutoResizeColumns();
            dgv.AllowUserToResizeColumns = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

- Thanks for the solution above (To iterate through the `DataGridView.Columns`, change `AutoSizeMode` to a valid one, collect width value and set it back after change `AutoSizeMode` to `DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None`).
- I struggled with it, and noticed it won't work whenever it is called from the class constructor or any line before `Form.Show()` or `Form.ShowDialog()`. So I put this code snippet in the `Form.Shown` event and this works for me.
- My transformed code, reguardless of whatever `DataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode` set before, I use `DataGridViewColumn.GetPreferredWidth()` instead of changing `DataGridViewColumn.AutoSizeMode` and set the width value immediately, then change `DataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode` once:

  ```
  private void form_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
          foreach (DataGridViewColumn c in dataGridView.Columns)
              c.Width = c.GetPreferredWidth(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells, true);
          dataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.None;
  }
  ```
- Be sure to set

  ```
          dataGridView.AllowUserToResizeColumns = true;
  ```
- I don't know how come this only works after the form is shown.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this in VB and prefer to split it out to a method that I placed in a Module. You can add the Fill column as another ByRef parameter if desired.

```
''' <summary>
''' Makes all columns in a DataGridView autosize based on displayed cells,
''' while leaving the column widths user-adjustable.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="dgv">A DataGridView to adjust</param>
Friend Sub MakeAdjustableAutoSizedGridCols(ByRef dgv As DataGridView)
    Dim width As Integer

    For Each col As DataGridViewColumn In dgv.Columns
        col.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells
        width = col.Width
        col.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None
        col.Width = width
    Next
    dgv.AllowUserToResizeColumns = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
   grd.DataSource = getDataSource();

    if (grd.ColumnCount > 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < grd.ColumnCount-1; i++)
            grd.Columns[i].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;

        grd.Columns[grd.ColumnCount-1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
    }

    if (grd.ColumnCount==1)
        grd.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
```

All columns will adapt to the content except the last one will fill the grid.

Answer (score 0):

With $array being the contents of a PSCustomObject, this works:

```
$dataGridView1.DataSource=[collections.arraylist]($array)
$dataGridView1.Columns | Foreach-Object{$_.AutoSizeMode = [System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode]::AllCells}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could do like below

`dataGrid1.AutoResizeColumns();`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).