# No cursor when resizing datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, resize, cursor

When i'm trying to resize datagridview columns the resize cursor appears only when i roll over header. However, when i roll over in between cells, resize cursor doesn't show at all.

I have noticed if i set ColumnHeadersVisible = false it fixes the problem and i see resize cursor between columns. However, i need header to be visible, any idea how to make it work all together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the default behavior for DataGridView(and for most Grids). One way to handle your situation, I believe, is to handle that manually; for instance, subclass the grid and, catch the mouse-entering-in-cell event, change the cursor to resize-cursor, and then resize column upon mousedown. Well, just thinking out loud.

**--EDIT--**

This is in response to your comment. Assuming that by "automated" you mean 'auto resize of columns', please check the [`.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autosizecolumnsmode.aspx);

> This property lets you configure the control so that column widths are automatically adjusted either to fill the control or to fit cell contents

Also, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025670/how-do-you-automatically-resize-columns-in-a-datagridview-control-and-allow-the-u/1031871#1031871) might help.

Comment: thanks! but is there any automated way that i just missed out?