# Force resize of DataGridView columns

Tags: c#, winforms

I've got a simple form with a DataGridView element on it. In the constructor the grid columns get added and the DataTable gets set. When I then call AutoResizeColumns() it doesn't resize the columns as it would when called by e.g. a button event.
The code looks like this (simplified):

```
public MyDialog()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   dgv.Columns.AddRange(SomeClass.MyColumns);
   dgv.DataSource = SomeClass.Table;
   // This doesn't work:
   dgv.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);
}
```

AutoResizeColumns() works in general but not at that point. Btw, I need this to implement a behavior like it is requested/described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025670/how-do-you-automatically-resize-columns-in-a-datagridview-control-and-allow-the-u/1992704#1992704). Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Additionally, I believe the object needs to be VISIBLE before the resize is done... for some reason, the painting doesn't appear to happen as one would expect.

Comment: Yes it does, I just confirmed that myself with a project I'm working on

Comment: For a DataGridView where I manually load rows (no datatable data source) I use the VisibleChanged event.  After all rows are loaded, it is fired.  Add my `AutoResizeColumns()` in there and you're good.  You can even check for visible = true for less overhead.

Comment: @Smitty-Werben-Jager-Manjenson, yes, VisibleChanged would work, but the underlying issue they had was resize BEFORE the object is visible has no true context of dimensions available.

Answer (score 16):

I had the same issue until I set the autosize mode:

```
dgv.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
```

Comment: Can you please add `dgv.` and a semicolon?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `AutoResizeColumns()` after your `DataGridView` has data in it. That is the reason. Make sure `SomeClass.Table` get the data before you call `AutoResizeColumns()`

Comment: I wanted the user to be able to resize anything and setting the columns all to none allowed me to do that. But I also wanted the initial display to auto-fit everything. So I put this line in the DataBindingComplete event on the data grid view and it allowed me to get the best of both worlds:

dataGridViewGameList.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);

Answer (score 0):

You also need to set AutoSizeColumnsMode of DataGridView