# How to set Gridview Column width as per database field width?

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop-application, gridviewcolumn

I am new to windows desktop application development.

I have a grid in which I am displaying list of customers whose bills are printed.

The form looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxXk4.png).

The grid in this form displays the list of all customers and it is bounded in the `Form_Load()` my code is :

```
private void SearchForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    cn = db.createConnection();
    if (cn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        cn.Close();
    cn.Open();
    cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select BillNo,PartyName,Address,City,State,BillDt from BillMaster", cn);
    da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    cn.Close();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    ds.Dispose();
}
```

But the width of the `PartyName` field is too short to read the full name. I want to customize the size of the all fields. How to do so?

Please help.

Comment: Do you want the width the be dynamic ? i.e. to match longest string ?

Comment: Yes Sir, I want to do same for all fields. @Ofiris

Comment: Ok, check my answer and have a look in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025670/how-do-you-automatically-resize-columns-in-a-datagridview-control-and-allow-the for more options.

Answer (score 2):

[AutoResizeColumns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autoresizecolumns.aspx)  is what you looking for.

```
dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
```

> AllCells - The column width adjusts to fit the contents of all cells in
>   the column, including the header cell.

Also, have a look in [DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewautosizecolumnmode.aspx)

Comment: Sir, can. U privide some code plzzz. Coz I actually dont know how to implement. As per my application

Comment: Add the first line where `dataGridView1 `is initialized.

Comment: Sir, I have placed the grid view at design time without any column specified. Will it be useful for that or I have to create an object of the grid in my code???

Comment: I tried creating the grid in my C# code. But also not working. Gives output as before. @Ofiris

Comment: Set it in the dgv properties