# DataGridView comboBoxColumn dropdownlist position

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

When a comboBoxColumn in a DataGridView is smaller in width than the dropdownlist, the dropdownlist will "overflow" to the column on the right. I would like to have a comboBoxColumn that expands the dropdown to the left. Is this doable with a custom comboBoxColumn class?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just set the AutoSizeColumnMode of the gridview?

Alternatively, [this might answer your question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025670/how-do-you-automatically-resize-columns-in-a-datagridview-control-and-allow-the)