# Automatically adjust columns' width to fit in the datagridview

Tags: c#

I have a DataGridView that has a multiple number of columns. The number of these columns changes based on the conditions met. How do I automatically change each columns width to fit in the datagridview without needing to have a horizontal scroll?

Comment: Set width of gridview to 100%

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you automatically resize columns in a DataGridView control AND allow the user to resize the columns on that same grid?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025670/how-do-you-automatically-resize-columns-in-a-datagridview-control-and-allow-the)

Answer (score 3):

```
grid.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
grid.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.None;
```

Also, I have set the

```
grid.AllowUserToOrderColumns = true;
grid.AllowUserToResizeColumns = true;
```

Now the column widths can be changed and the columns can be rearranged by the user. That works pretty well for me.

Maybe that will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Set DataGridVIew AutoSizeColumnsMode proerty to DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill. It will change columns width to fit datagridview size. Columns text may not be visible depending upon number of columns.