# How to auto resize column width according to content of cells with ingoring the contents in the hidden rows

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am working on DataGridView control in C# for Windows Form Application.

I can auto-rize the column witht the code below. But I want to auto-resize the column only by the contents in visible rows. Is there any way to do that?

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string colName = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";

            DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
            tbl.Columns.Add(colName);

            DataRow row = tbl.NewRow();
            row[colName] = "ss";
            tbl.Rows.Add(row);

            row = tbl.NewRow();
            string val2 = "vvvvvvvvvvvvvvv";
            row[colName] = val2;
            tbl.Rows.Add(row);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = tbl;

            tbl.DefaultView.RowFilter = 
                colName + " <> '"+ val2 + "'";
        }

        private void dataGridView1_ColumnWidthChanged(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridViewColumn col = e.Column;
            col.Width = col.GetPreferredWidth(
                    DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCellsExceptHeader,
                    true);
        }
```

Comment: may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025670/how-do-you-automatically-resize-columns-in-a-datagridview-control-and-allow-the

Comment: what if you check your `RowFilter` condition in `dataGridView1_ColumnWidthChanged` event so the code only works on visible rows? although you might need to loop through rows for that, but I can't think of anything else. the method @Jazb suggested is also a way to cover this problem. it can be tweaked to work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

wonder have you tried changing [AutoSizeColumnsMode] on Properties?
[VisualStudioProperties-F4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eP6Jq.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34211339)